# Mapping and sorting lists of Haskell tuples

Tags: beginner, haskell, sorting

I'm a newbie with Haskell and I'm trying to learn the language and its idioms while working through a small data analysis project.  The first step of my analysis is to take a very long list of data, generate the set of ngrams from that list, then create a histogram from the generated set of ngrams.

This approach seems to work nicely:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Arrow

histogram :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
histogram = map (head &&& length) . group . sort

ngrams :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
ngrams n xs
     | nx == xs  = [xs]
     | otherwise = [nx] ++ (ngrams n (tail xs))
     where nx = take n xs
```

The next step is divide each ngram frequency by the total number of ngrams and then take the inverse of each of these values.

```
(//) a b = fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b

mapOverSnd :: (a -> b) -> [(c,a)] -> [(c,b)]
mapOverSnd f = map (fst &&& f . snd)

...

let myData = (long list of values)
let my3grams = ngrams 3 myData
let freq3grams = histogram my3grams
let novelty3grams = mapOverSnd ((1/) . (//(length freq3grams))) freq3grams
```

My first question is.. is this a reasonable way to be doing this?  Is there a more idiomatic way to accomplish mapOverSnd?  I don't yet have much dexterity wielding higher order structures to accomplish my tasks.

Also, I'd like to sort the resultant structure: first by the value stored in snd, then by the value stored in fst.  I'd like the primary sort to be descending and the secondary sort to be ascending.  This works:

```
my2TupleOrdering :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a,b) -> (a,b) -> Ordering
my2TupleOrdering (a1,b1) (a2,b2)
               | b1 < b2   = GT
               | b1 > b2   = LT
               | a1 < a2   = LT
               | a1 > a2   = GT
               | otherwise = EQ
```

however, I was wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to say "sort this 2-tuple, first by snd descending, then by fst ascending."

I realize these are relatively minor questions, but I'm interested in exploring the expressive power of Haskell and figured 'code review' might be the correct forum.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mapping over second

It is surprising that you know about `&&&`, but not `second`, also from Arrows:

```
mapOverSnd f = map (second f)
```

`second` is of type `Arrow a => a b c -> a (d, b) (d, c)`, which boils down to `(b->c) -> (d,b) -> (d,c)` here.

Alternatively, you can take advantage that pairs are a `Functor` instance: `fmap (+1) ("...",10) = ("...",11)

```
mapOverSnd f = map (fmap f)
```

## Definitions can be infix

You wrote `(//) a b =`, but definitions can be infix, too:

```
a // b = fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b
```

## your2TupleOrdering

2-tuples are simply called pairs. `sort` needs a function like `compare`, so define yours in terms of `compare`. Take advantage of `Ordering` being an instance of `Monoid`:

```
myPairOrdering (a1,b1) (a2,b2) = compare a1 a2 `mappend` compare b2 b1
```

The `Monoid` instance of `Ordering` is:

```
mempty = EQ
EQ `mappend` y = y -- only if left side equals, use right
x  `mappend` _ = x -- shortcut otherwise
```

## ngrams

Any solution to `ngrams` will be ugly because you don't want the very last elements which are below the minimum length. You are forcing an `Eq` constraint, which is not necessary. Avoid by comparing the `length`. Another solution is

```
ngrams' n = filter ((==n).length) . map (take n) . tails
```

The `filter` part here is ugly.

## The let-chain

You can condense the `let`-chain with composition, cutting out `freq3grams` and `my3grams`. At some point in you haskell journey, you will do that. When you grow wiser, you will value readability over succinctness. Long story short: This part is OK.

Comment: Great feedback.  Thank you so much for taking the time to walk through this.